# Android app login screen - wrong variable and shared preferences comparison

Tags: java, android, variables, authentication, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to store encrypted password in SharedPreferences of my app. According to logs password is saved correctly and matches typed password after encryption, but in the if comparison they aren't equal. Every time it runs else instruction. I can't find what's wrong so I'm asking for help!
BTW what would be better, more secure way of storing password, even encrypted?

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String PREFERENCES_NAME = "passHashed";
    private static final String PREFERENCES_TEXT_FIELD = "textField";

    public EditText Password;
    public TextView Info;
    private String passSavedHash;

    private SharedPreferences preferences;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
        Info = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Info);
        Button loginBtn = findViewById(R.id.loginButton);

        preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_NAME, AppCompatActivity.MODE_PRIVATE);

        if(!passRead().equals("0")) {
            passSavedHash = passRead();
            Log.d("Password", "passHashed: " + passSavedHash);
        }
        else{
            loginBtn.setText(R.string.set_pass);
        }
    }


    public void onClickValidate(View view) throws Exception {
        String password = Password.getText().toString();
        String passHash = CipherAlgorithm.encrypt(password);

        Log.d("Password", "passHashed:    " + passSavedHash);
        Log.d("Password", "passSavedHash: " + passHash);

        if(passRead().equals("0") && password.length() > 3) {
            passSave();
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else {
            if (Objects.equals(passSavedHash, passHash)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Info.setText(R.string.wron_pass);
            }
        }
        Password.setText("");

    }

    private void passSave() throws Exception {
        SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditor = preferences.edit();
        String editTextData = CipherAlgorithm.encrypt(Password.getText().toString());
        preferencesEditor.putString(PREFERENCES_TEXT_FIELD, editTextData);
        preferencesEditor.commit();
    }

    private String passRead() {
        return preferences.getString(PREFERENCES_TEXT_FIELD, "0");
    }

}
```

Comment: I think you should use equals() method of String instead of Objects.
For example "Objects.equals(passSavedHash, passHash)" should change to:
"passSavedHash.equals(passHash)"
Because equals method of String check for content, not object reference.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's no difference. But now i found out that password saved in SharedPreferences is opening a new line after itself like it was password + enter. I'm gonna look at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. It was problem with whitespace. I added trim() method to passwords strings and now it works fine!